# LUA Pattern to retrieve a specific part of text from a string

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

So I have a string in Lua that is exactly like the following:

```
[[
  en[What is your job]
  pt[Qual é o seu trabalho?]
]]
```

As you might expect, I want to sometimes retrieve anything inside "en[]" and in other times "pt[]" and put the text inside a new variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: What pattern did you try? Even if it's not working now.

Comment: Yu Hao. Sorry. Did not see your question. I was trying `pt%[(.*)%]` and `en%[(.*)%]`.

DavisDude already helped me fixing it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit: Improved speed by removing some concatenation.

This should work:

```
    String = [[
        en[What is your job]
        pt[Qual é o seu trabalho?]
    ]]

    function RetrieveElementFromString( String, Element, ContainerOpen, ContainerClose ) -- String is the "[[]]" part.
        return String:match( Element .. ContainerOpen .. '(.-)' .. ContainerClose )
    end

    print( RetrieveElementFromString( String, 'en', '%[', '%]' ) ) -- > What is your job
```

Comment: Didn't work here... what I tried is:

`localeMessage = string.find([[ en[Hello!] ]], 'en%[(.-[^%]])%]')`

`print(localeMessage)` outputs "2"

Edit: changed to string:match and got what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad. `string.find` would have returned it as the third argument, the first two being the start and end (respectively) of the string.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking about it and realized that I had an extraneous concatenation. Now it is shorter, using less concatenation, making it faster.